# Signal-handling between threads

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, signals, pseudocode

I'm new to concurrent programming and I got around this question I can't really understand what's wrong with, consider the following pseudo-code  with x being a shared (conditional) variable initialized with 0:

`signal(c)
 wait(c)
 x = x + 1
 signal(c)`

What are the possible results for x, running 2 threads (concurrently) in a single processor?

Answer (score 0):

After executing both threads either everything went fine and x = 2 or both "x=x+1" line are executed at the same time and then x = 1 because both thread read the initial value of x as 0 at the same time.

Comment: Is it possible that both threads emit a signal at the same time and none catches it, so both will have to wait for the missing signals resulting in a deadlock, and x ends with 0 ?

Comment: I'm not sure what "signal(c)" is supposed to do nor what is the nature of 'c'. The result will change if 'c' is a binary value or a counter or something else.